# Perfmon in Windows 2008 R2 with multiple graphs with seperate durations

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, perfmon

In Windows 2003 we could open perfmon and then add multiple snapins to have a console that displays perfmon say for example in 3 hours, 12 hours and 24 hours in the same .MSC. It was then easy to navigate the history and compare over time values with various resolutions.

This was accomplished by starting perfmon, going to the console root then add/remove snap-in + Add + ActiveX Control + System Monitor Control.

Is this possible in Windows 2008 R2? My main objective is to be able to see various time spans in seperate graphs without obviously opening up 3 seperate perfmon instances.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just stumbled on the answer.

Save the 3, 12 and 24 hour setting to seperate html files. Then you simply open them all in seperate tabs within the browser so it's IE the container instead of MMC but it has the desired effect of tabbing through the 3 different ranges to keep an eye on things.

that's pretty cool.